# Height transition not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

i tried putting that code on #subnavlist li but it wont work. Basically i was trying to delay the hover height

```
 height: 0;
-webkit-transition: height 200ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: height 200ms ease-in;
-o-transition: height 200ms ease-in;
transition: height 200ms ease-in;
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
* { padding:0; margin:0; }
li { list-style: none: list-type: none; }
li div { max-height:0; overflow:hidden; background: #000; color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
li span { display: block; padding: 4px; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; background: #000;}
li span:hover + div {
    max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Something</span>
    <div>
      Some content <br>
      Some content <br>
      Some content <br>
      Some content <br>
      Some content <br>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Transitions need a defined start and a defined end state. You do not have a defined end height (`auto` is not defined) so you cannot transition from `height:0` to `height:auto`

Your JSFiddle does not contain any height transitioning code either.

A workaround for you is to use `max-height` and transition that from `0` to some moderately large value.

Comment: i dont have a height auto

Comment: is there anyway to adjust a block?

Comment: You cannot transition between `display: block` and `display: none`. How should the browser do the transition? opacity? height? width? I have added a code snippet that will help you modify your CSS to achieve the effect you want.

Comment: @JohnTso I was working on your fiddle and eventually managed to make it work. Although I hadn't seen Adam's answer until now, the changes I made used basically everything that he included in his answer, so I'll post your updated working fiddle here instead of creating a new answer: http://jsfiddle.net/k3gocz0y/26/

Comment: so i can change ul#subnavlist to have a max-height: 100px. so why isnt it working when i define the height at 0 and use transition (in ul#subnavlist li)?

Comment: God this annoys me so much haha, I had the same answer like 10 mins ago but doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS transition property `transition-delay;`

This solves your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/cdxbk443/

Or without animation: http://jsfiddle.net/vd9qz3xs/

To increase the duration of the delay, simply add a few more seconds to the `transition-delay` property of `ul#subnavlist`.

```
ul#navlist {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
ul#navlist a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
ul#navlist, ul#subnavlist, li#subactive, ul#navlist ul, ul#navlist li, #active {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 250px !important;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul#navlist li {
    float: left;
}
ul#navlist li a:hover {
    color: #F7A11A;
}
#left-arrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    left: 100px;
    border-top: 10px solid #404040;
}
#d1 span {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: -15px;
}
ul#subnavlist {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 1;
    height: 0px;
    width:250px !important;
    z-index: 9;
    font-size: 8pt;
    padding-top: 5px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:250px !important;
}
ul#subnavlist li {
    float: none;
    width:250px !important;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
ul#subnavlist li a {
    color: white;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
ul#navlist li:hover ul#subnavlist {
    visibility: visible;
    transition-delay: 0.4s;
    background: #404040;
    font-size: 8pt;
    padding-top: 5px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height: auto;
    width:250px !important;
    border-top: 6px solid #F7A11A;
}
ul#navlist li:hover ul#subnavlist li a {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    border: none;
    padding: 7px 10px;
}
#container1 {
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #404040;
}
#navlist:hover #left-arrow {
    border-top: 10px solid white;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateX(118px) rotate(180deg);
    border-top: 10px solid #F7A11A;
}
#navlist:hover #couldBeAnImage {
    border-top: 10px solid #F7A11A;
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
}
#navlist:hover #d1 span {
    color: #F7A11A;
}
#left-arrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    float: left;
    border-top: 10px solid white;
    top: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .42s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform .42s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .42s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a `transition-delay` property. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition-delay/

They way your wrote your short-hand transition property only includes the transition-duration.

transition: [transition-property] [transition-duration] [transition-timing-function] [transition-delay];

So just add your delay duration to the end of your lines like so:

```
-webkit-transition: height 200ms ease-in 200ms;
-moz-transition: height 200ms ease-in 200ms;
-o-transition: height 200ms ease-in 200ms;
transition: height 200ms ease-in 200ms;
```

Comment: im not sure why but i tried and it still doesn't work. could be because it is a block?

Comment: No, it's because you have display: none in your element. This causes it to be removed from the element flow and your transition to have unexpected behaviors.